# Compare Day From Current Date And redirect page After Comparison

Tags: php, html, date

I am new to php. I want to redirect user on specific date in every month.

I tried following code, but it is not working.

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');

$date = date('Y-m-d');
$dateblock = date ('d', strtotime($date));

if ($dateblock ="2" || $dateblock ="5" || $dateblock ="9" || $dateblock ="11" || $dateblock ="13" || $dateblock ="16" || $dateblock ="18" || $dateblock ="21" || $dateblock ="23" || $dateblock ="25" || $dateblock ="27" || $dateblock ="29" || $dateblock ="30") {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>
    <img src="images/sorry.png" />
</center>

</body>
</html>

  <?}else{

echo "Redirecting You..... Please Wait...";
header('Refresh: 3;url=pagexyz.php');

}?>
```

Basically I want to show **pagexyz.php** only on dates in month except dates used in above if statement.

Or

is there any other way to hide **pagexyz.php** on specific dates in each month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also utilize an `in_array()` function for this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                             // ^ big letter K
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$dateblock = date ('d', strtotime($date));
$restricted_days = array(2,5,9,11,13,16,18,21,23,29,30);
?>

<?php if(in_array($dateblock, $restricted_days)): ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <center>
    <img src="images/sorry.png" />
    </center>

    </body>
</html>
<?php else: ?>
    <h1>Redirecting!! Please wait!!!</h1>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.google.com" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yes, it worked....thank you. May I know, which factor in my code was creating problem?

Comment: @chplab the error was on the `date_default_timezone_set()`, its strict on the values inside, since you inputted small letter `k` inside it `Kolkata`. i turn on error reporting